# pandas dataframe.to_sql() works on jupyter but not on VScode with same parameters

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have a simple code that I'm running fine on jupyter notebook:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy

user_id = 'userid'
password = 'password'
server = 'server'
database_name = 'database_name'
driver = 'SQL Server'

connection_string = (
           f'DRIVER={{{driver}}};'
           f'SERVER={server};'
           f'DATABASE={database_name};'
           f'UID={user_id};'
           f'PWD={password};')

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE [Startup];")

conn.commit()

connection_string = f'mssql+pyodbc://{user_id}:{password}@{server}/{database_name}?driver={driver}'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)

df_clean.to_sql('Startup', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)


conn.commit()
```

This is working fine (I know that by using if_exists = 'replace' I don't need the TRUNCATE, but as for now it's fine like this).

The problem is that I wrote the same code in VScode, and the

```
df_clean.to_sql('Startup', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

is throwing an error:

```
(pyodbc.Error) ('HY104', '[HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Valore di precisione non valido. (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
[SQL: SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME]
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE ([INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) OR [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))]
[parameters: ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'Startup', 'dbo')]
```

Valore di precisione non valido is italian for precision value not valid.
I googled it and I found that the data that I'm trying to insert into the db does not correspond with the table already existent, but then why it's working fine on jupyter?

The section of the code before the .to_sql in VScode is also working fine (the TRUNCATE query is working), and I tried to save the df_clean before pushing it and the file is also fine.

All of the packages that I need are installed in the venv in VScode.
I printed both the connection string and the engine in both Jup and VS and they are exactly the same.

edit: I tried to create a new venv in jupyter with only python installed, I then installed the packages from vs code and I got the same error.
The problem now is that the first (working) try was on the root env of anaconda jupyter, so I have like thousand of packages already installed. How do I know which one(s) do I need for this project?

edit2 SOLVED: i added use_setinputsizes=False in the create_engine and for some reasons it works

Comment: Have you tried being specific about drivers? `driver = 'SQL Server'` might choose to use SQL Server Native Client 10 or 11 on Windows, neither of which is distributed or supported by Microsoft any more. You might get more consistency if you were to use modern and supported drivers such as `driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'` or  `driver = 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'`, depending on which you have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using use_setinputsizes=False in the create_engine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).